# "How to add search filter in 'django rest_framework'"

Tags: django-rest-framework

"I want search in my db eg.www.127.0.0.1:8000/q?lno=a12345 or lnocontain=---2345 that contain the last 2345"

**sample_db**

1. lno=a12345
2. lno=b23345

   .........

   ........
   etc

**model.py**

```
    lno = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
```

**view.py**

````
    class GetPostOneL(ListCreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = OneLSerializers
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
        pagination_class = CustomPagination
        authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)


        def get_queryset(self):
            reseller = self.request.user
            if reseller.is_authenticated:
                return OneL.objects.filter(reseller=reseller)
            return OneL.objects.none()

        def get(self, request):
            onesales = self.get_queryset()
            paginate_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(onesales)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(paginate_queryset, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)```
````

Comment: By default, it's not possible. For more info refer this, [**`DRF-Filtering`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

Comment: If i use raw query ,is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more general search scope like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/?search=a12345`

And inside you logic:

```
class GetPostOneL(ListCreateAPIView):
    ...

    def get(self, request):
        onesales = self.get_queryset()
        search_query = request.GET.get('search', False)

        if search_query:
            onesales = onesales.filter(lno__icontains=search_query)

        paginate_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(onesales)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(paginate_queryset, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

In case you want to explicitly search by word ending, you can look into:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#endswith

Comment: **Its work ,but i'm using dynamic_rest,now ,drest can do all filter with just a few line of code**